# how to begin moving cell with long press gesture?

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView with several UITableViewCells in it. I'd like to long press on a cell to begin move it and keep holding on it and drag to move it. But i don't know how.

I added a long press gesture on table view, when user long pressed , set tableview's editing to YES:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                                     initWithTarget:self
                                                     action:@selector(handleTableViewLongPress:)];
[_tableView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];

- (void)handleTableViewLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        return;
    [_tableView setEditing:YES];
}
```

And the tableview could move cell with two methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    //update datasource
}
```

But with these code user must use two touch to move a cell: one is to set the tableview to editing state, another is to move cell. What i want is to allow user use one touch to do this.

Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: yes, i have. but after long press, i need another touch to move cell. what i want is the user could use only one touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this UITableView subclass: [Move table view](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/fmmovetableview)

Comment: Wonderful! this is exactly what i want